# I am getting a weird android runtime error , and the application is to search for events happenning in a place based on location?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, runtime-error

The errors in the log-cat are,

```
 10-27 06:07:31.428: E/AndroidRuntime(17826): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-27 06:07:31.428: E/AndroidRuntime(17826): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
    10-27 06:07:31.428: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
    10-27 06:07:31.428: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
    10-27 06:07:31.428: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
    10-27 06:07:31.428: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
    10-27 06:07:31.428: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    10-27 06:07:31.428: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    10-27 06:07:31.428: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    10-27 06:07:31.428: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    10-27 06:07:31.428: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
    10-27 06:07:31.428: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):
```

at

```
package pt.up.fe.aroundme.android;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import pt.up.fe.aroundme.R;
import pt.up.fe.aroundme.android.activities.LandmarkActivity;
import pt.up.fe.aroundme.android.activities.MapActivity;
import pt.up.fe.aroundme.android.exceptions.UserLocationIsNullException;
import pt.up.fe.aroundme.controllers.AroundMeController;
import pt.up.fe.aroundme.models.Landmark;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polygon;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolygonOptions;

public class MapManager {

    private static final int DEFAULT_RADIUS = 25;

    private final MapActivity mapActivity;

    private final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private final GoogleMap map;
    private final UserLocationManager userlocationManager;
    private final AroundMeController aroundmeController;

    private Integer radiusValue = DEFAULT_RADIUS;
    private Polygon radiusPolygon;
    private HashMap<Marker, Landmark> loadedMarkers;

    public MapManager(final MapActivity mapActivity) {
        this.mapActivity = mapActivity;

        this.map =
                ((SupportMapFragment) this.getMapActivity()
                        .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                        .getMap();

        this.map.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        this.map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        this.map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(final Marker marker) {
                final Intent intent =
                        new Intent(MapManager.this.mapActivity
                                .getApplicationContext(),
                                LandmarkActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(LandmarkActivity.LANDMARK_ID_KEY,
                        MapManager.this.loadedMarkers.get(marker).getId());
                MapManager.this.mapActivity.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        this.map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                        new LatLng(41.1782628, -8.5947189)).zoom(12).build()),
                650, null);

        this.userlocationManager =
                new UserLocationManager(this, (LocationManager) this
                        .getMapActivity().getSystemService(
                                Context.LOCATION_SERVICE));

        this.aroundmeController = new AroundMeController(this);

        this.sharedPreferences =
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this
                        .getMapActivity().getApplicationContext());
        this.loadedMarkers = new HashMap<Marker, Landmark>();

    }

    // MAP UPDATE METHODS

    public void update() throws UserLocationIsNullException {
        this.updateRadius();
        this.updateLandmarksMarkers();
    }

    public void updateRadius() throws UserLocationIsNullException {
        // TODO refactor radius_checkbox_key string
        if( !this.sharedPreferences.getBoolean("radius_checkbox_key", true) ) { return; }

        this.radiusValue =
                this.sharedPreferences.getInt("radius",
                        R.integer.radius_default);
        Log.d("updateRadius()", this.radiusValue + "");

        final PolygonOptions options = new PolygonOptions();

        // TODO refactor: create class with this method as static...dunno...
        final double R = 6371d; // earth's mean radius in km
        final double d = this.radiusValue / R; // radius given in km
        final double lat1 =
                Math.toRadians(this.userlocationManager.getLatitude());
        final double lon1 =
                Math.toRadians(this.userlocationManager.getLongitude());

        for(int x = 0; x <= 720; x++) {
            final double brng = Math.toRadians(x);
            final double latitudeRad =
                    Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(d) + Math.cos(lat1)
                            * Math.sin(d) * Math.cos(brng));
            final double longitudeRad =
                    (lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) * Math.sin(d)
                            * Math.cos(lat1), Math.cos(d) - Math.sin(lat1)
                            * Math.sin(latitudeRad)));
            options.add(new LatLng(Math.toDegrees(latitudeRad), Math
                    .toDegrees(longitudeRad)));
        }

        if( this.radiusPolygon != null ) {
            this.radiusPolygon.remove();
        }

        this.radiusPolygon =
                this.map.addPolygon(options.strokeColor(Color.LTGRAY)
                        .strokeWidth(2).fillColor(Color.LTGRAY));
    }

    public void updateLandmarksMarkers() {
        this.clearLandmarks();

        try {
            this.aroundmeController.refreshLandmarks(this.userlocationManager
                    .getLocation(), this.radiusValue);
        } catch (final UserLocationIsNullException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final List<Landmark> loadedLandmarks =
                this.aroundmeController.getLoadedLandmarks();
        Log.d("updateLandmarksMarkers()", this.loadedMarkers.size() + "");
        for(final Landmark landmark: loadedLandmarks) {
            this.addMarker(landmark);
        }
    }

    private void clearLandmarks() {

        final Set<Marker> loadedMarkers = this.loadedMarkers.keySet();

        for(final Marker marker: loadedMarkers) {
            Log.d("clearLandmarkMarkers()", "clearing...");
            marker.remove();
        }

        this.loadedMarkers = new HashMap<Marker, Landmark>();
    }

    public void toggleMapType(final View view) {
        this.map.setMapType(this.map.getMapType() == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL
                ? GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID : GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }

    public void addMarker(final Landmark landmark) {
        if( this.loadedMarkers.containsValue(landmark) ) { return; }


    public Location getMyLocation() {
        return this.map.getMyLocation();
    }

}
```

How can I resolve this? urgently needed help. How can I solve this android runtime errros. I have tried loading the libraries and everything?

I have tried everything on the solutions present , just check please.

Comment: have you referenced the google play services library project properly?

Comment: 11-12 22:33:19.625: E/Google Maps Android API(19245): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
11-12 22:33:19.630: E/Google Maps Android API(19245): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: pt.up.fe.aroundme, API Key: AIzaSyCqxiskhqI2b11GVkBMEDbA13WT3h0e7rA, Certificate Fingerprint: 6752DE27697D4A6741A8BFB7E8D819260ED4D0D4
 Getting this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
```

usually indicates that you have some problem with `google-play-service` library, you have some problem with the way to reference it.

You can go over the first three steps of this guide I wrote:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

and make sure you are making it right.

Comment: This really helped , Though could you tell me a way to generate my API key yet again , coz it's saying failed authentication even though I asked for a key agin ? I am using mac so that keystore command how do you execute to get the SHA1 fingerprint?

Comment: I don't own a Mac so I can't really help you with this one, but I'm sure there are enough tutorials for mac you can find on the web.

Comment: 11-12 22:33:19.625: E/Google Maps Android API(19245): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
11-12 22:33:19.630: E/Google Maps Android API(19245): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: pt.up.fe.aroundme, API Key: AIzaSyCqxiskhqI2b11GVkBMEDbA13WT3h0e7rA, Certificate Fingerprint: 6752DE27697D4A6741A8BFB7E8D819260ED4D0D4 This is the error I get!

Comment: have you looked at this guide: http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403 for getting the API key?

Comment: yeah I had a look at this , but then I am a beginner at this so I have a doubt , I am using multiple package name's so to register it at the console which one should i use?

Comment: as described there you should add something like this: 45:B5:E4:6F:36:AD:0A:98:94:B4:02:66:2B:12:17:F2:56:26:A0:E0;com.example.your_project_name to the API Console, go over all the steps of both guides and make sure you complete them all

Comment: Hey I just upgraded the version I was using for google play services and I am getting the previously descibed errrors (fatal errors) again? any solution on that?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using gcm.jar then may be jar file is not proper compressed or one thing you can so use google play service library project with your project and build it properly.I Hope,This will shorted out your problem.

Comment: 11-12 23:15:29.455: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(12135): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
This is the error I get at the log cat ?

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError Exception says that the problem is in the setup of the Google play services library
please be sure you added the google_play_services correctly in ur project [Set Up Google Play Services SDK](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to play the Google play Service in to your Work Space and and try to import the google play service and add that Google play service as the project which you need ,by right clicking on that project go to properties-->Android--->add the Google play service
[with figure](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)